# Gain for runtimes as a function of different possible vectorizations

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization, compiler-optimization

I am doing tests with `gcc-4.9` on a simple example for studying vectorization (my little code computes the sum of `double` 2 arrays and store results into output array).

From what I have seen on web, there seems to exist :

1. SSE vectorization (128 bits = 16 bytes = `2*sizeof(double)`
2. AVX vectorization (256 bits = 32 bytes = `4*sizeof(double)`
3. AVX2 vectorization (512 bits = 64 bytes = `8*sizeof(double)`

My issue is that in three above cases, I always get a gain (between no-vectorized and vectorized versions) roughly equal to 2 (quite a mean gain of 1.7).

I think that I don'use the good compilation options. Here what I did :

1. For SSE : `gcc-mp-4.9 -std=c99 -Wa,-q -O3 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec main.c`
2. For AVX : `gcc-mp-4.9 -std=c99 -Wa,-q -O3 -march=corei7-avx -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec main.c`
3. For AVX2 : `gcc-mp-4.9 -std=c99 -Wa,-q -O3 -march=core-avx2 -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec main.c`

When I run this 3 cases, I always get a factor around `2` whereas I expect to reach a `factor 4` for `AVX` and a `factor 8` for `AVX2`.

Processor on my MacBook pro is : `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4960HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz`

Anyone could tell me the different flags to active AVX and AVX2 vectorization ?

Maybe, my corei7 doesn't support these vectorizations (just SSE ?).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your processor [seems to support them](http://ark.intel.com/products/76088/Intel-Core-i7-4960HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz), so that's not the issue

Comment: How big are those arrays?

Comment: By the way, correct me if I'm wrong, but  [AVX2 only uses 256 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)

Comment: I am doing tests from 10e+5 to 10e+8 elements for my arrays of double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've implemented the necessary unrolling and the right packing calls, then it is likely that the issue here could be memory related:

1) You'll be hammering the cache a little harder as result of the larger blocks of memory you need to exploit the more generous packing.

2) You may need to help the compiler out here by telling that you want your data to be 32byte aligned (this will help with optimisation). Look up "#pragma vector aligned" it may or may not help.

3) There may also be an overhead if your array size is not a multiple of the packing - so for AVX2 this would be a multiple of 8. Some time may be spent in the "remainder" loop (but this should be a relatively small overhead).

4) Try reducing the degree of optimisation to -O2. Sometimes the more you tell the compiler to take charge of the less efficient your code can become.

But again you'll probably hit a "cache-efficiency" issue with larger packing operations (you'll likely be moving from L1 to L2).

Comment: What do you mean by "the necessary unrolling and the right packing calls" ? could you give me an example ?

Comment: It's the implicit (not explicit) unrolling that comes with vectorisation; if you're looping through an array your step is equal to your packing - I'm sure you did this but it's one of those things you could easily forget (e.g. for(i = 0; i < N; i+=8) ).

Comment: If this is implicit, I haven't got to specify it and modify the step of my loop (which is equal to 1), it's automatic ?

Comment: Are you using intrinsics. If you're doing aligned allocation then yes you can increment by 1 but you can make more work here too. For me it is just cleaner to pack your data into the new types (e.g. SIMD: m128d) within your loop then do your addition using the appropriate intrinsic function in which case you want to be stepping by 2. see: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1jq-MOwK1oMFr9iXoGJITBzA7bTeZ-roLDM38_5zR3Ek/edit#slide=id.g11cd0a5b7_164

Comment: Seeing what OpenMP does without the Hand instructions would be worthwhile. You probably want to align the data on 64 byte boundaries using a #pragma in any case.

Comment: @cdcdcd I didn't know intrinsics, just only flags for specifiying vectorization and it seems to be powerful because it allows to vectorize explicitly loops into code. By the way, could you tell me how to align arrays on 64 bytes (for example) when I allocate them ? thanks

Comment: You should be able to use the aligned_malloc() function to do this explicitly  and it is worth looking into the #pragma vector align and when and where to use it. There are other things worth using too and if you compile with optimisation the compiler may do a lot of the work for you without you having to use the intrinsics but you can never be sure without disassembling. Here is good link:https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/data-alignment-to-assist-vectorization I recommend you start here.

Comment: BTW, only use doubles if you need to. floats may be fine for what you want. As a general rule the smaller the data type generally the better vectorisation will perform as you're helping with caching too.